# Indication whether the content is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in front-end and have following problem. 
First input on page(class="form-control") is prepared for some system ID. After click on button it should fill others disabled inputs with properties like name, address,... It works fine, now I would like to delete content of disabled inputs in case that content of first ID input has changed.

All I have is something like this.

CSS:

```
<div class="idWrap">
    @Html.LabeledEditorFor(o => o.Id)
</div>

//BUTTON HERE

<fieldset disabled>
    @Html.LabeledEditorFor(o => o.FirstName)
    @Html.LabeledEditorFor(o => o.LastName)
    @Html.LabeledEditorFor(o => o.Address1)
</fieldset>
```

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"placeholder", "XXXXXX"},
    {"class", "form-control"}
})
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.idWrap, .form-control').focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        //GOT STUCK HERE
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to see what you have exactly without a codepen or something.

You can delete the value ('content' as you describe) by using jQuery [val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

First we can check that an input is disabled:

```
var isDisabled = $('input').is(':disabled');
```

If it is disabled, change the value:

```
if(isDisabled) {
  $(this).val('');
}
```

So for your case, you could combine this with an [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$('input').each(function(index, elm){
    var isDisabled = $(elm).is(':disabled');   
    if(isDisabled) {
      $(this).val('');
    }   
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhx6ekma/)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just put your code into $('.idWrap').change(function() block and have working solution. 
Thanks!

Comment: @JanKirchner Pleasure! Glad I could help :)